# Bloomberg Zero Coupon Rates

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve, bloomberg, curve-fitting

As some of your may know from my other posts, I am working on a Dynamic Nelson Siegel (DNS) based relative value trading model. On simulated data (which satisfies all the assumptions) of the DNS it worked well (unsurprisingly).

However I now need to get real data/results.

Part of the logic of the model is to look at the relative value of the most liquid points say 2,5,10y relative to all the remaining points.

So it's important that the zero coupon data represents ideally traded or at least traceable rates for all tenors rather than stale rates or even interpolated rates (as in this case I am just comparing different interpolation schemes!).

Does anyone know of a Bloomberg page that offers such rates? Or at least makes a distinction between which rates are real and which are interpolated?

Thanks Baz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the US Treasury market, zero coupon bonds are traded and they are called STRIPS. You can access them through "S GOVT" (coupon Strips) or "SP GOVT" (principal strips) on BBG.

With regard to relative value trading, it's actually pretty rare that we fit models to zeros, because a lot of them are not liquid and trade differently from their coupon counterparts.

Instead, what you should do is to fit your model to coupon bonds or par swaps directly. Like you said, you could potentially fit the 2y, 10y, and 30y bonds, then look at relative value elsewhere. Once you have fit a model to coupon Treasuries, you can then assess STRIPS against this same model.

For some real life examples, Tuckman's Fixed Income Securities (3rd Edition) Chapter 11 is quite good.

Comment: Thanks for this! I just want a zero coupon curve (derived from the most liquid instrumnents) not a curve of zero coupon isntruments sorry for any confusion. Problem seems to be that a lot of contributors to bloomberg only give market rates for a small subset of the curve with the remaining rates being interpolated. Bloomberg sets a minimum of four instruments for the zero curve construction (so would hope these at least are liquid)! But even if I know or could hazard a guess as to which instruments are being used it still leaves the problem that the remainig points are interpolated and so I

Comment: would just be comparing interpolation schemes rather than true relative value? Even if I fit to bonds and par swap directly it's still not possible to know which rates are market observed and which are interpolated? Plus when stripping you have to start making assumptions about the interpolation method i could very well use the Nelson Siegel framework but then my stripped "market" points would simply match the model and there would be no relative value.

Comment: @Bazman I might not be understanding you completely, but all bond prices on BBG should be quoted; i.e., the prices you see for all 300is Treasuries are tradable market prices, not model prices. As far as I know, the par swap rates are composite quotes too. At a minimum, 1y, 2y, 3y, 4y, 5y, 7y, 10y, 12y, 15y, 20y, 25y, and 30y par swap rates are quoted and not interpolated.

Comment: Thanks that helps but from talking to bloomberg it seems their only requirement for contributed curves is that a minimum of four rates be market observed (still trying to ascertain if four market rates is the norm of the exception). So you have a handle on how liquid rates like 11y are? Do they trade every day?

Comment: Hi @Bazman, I assume you're referring to BBG's curve builder when you mentioned "a minimum of four rates"? I was actually talking about retrieving quoted rates directly, using tickers such as USSW2, USSW10, etc. These should get you the latest quoted rates. 11yr is not actively traded...

Comment: Thanks again yes I realize that you were talking about getting the actual rates and it's a good idea and starting to look like a better option that using bbg zero curve based on only 4 market rates! However it still leaves the problem that you don't know for sure which rates are market rates i.e. traded that day and which are not. Obviously 2,5,10 will trade every day but 11y typically will not even though there is an 11y rate contributed each day (must be interpolated). Even if you can hazard a guess (or better find data to identify) which rates are traded at least daily. It still means

Comment: I either have to interpolate the non-liquid rates myself or take the bloomberg rates which are also interpolated anyway. So in effect when I compare the 1,5,10 to the 11y interpolated rate, I'm just comparing too different interpolation schemes. The 11y rate interpolate using my DNS model and the 11y rate interpolated by bloomberg this is not really in the spirit of the model but it's hard to see how to get round it.

Comment: I mean even can I even be sure that the 12y and 15y rates are traded daily and so their quote is a true market quote and not just an interpolated value?

Comment: I'd do a GIP (e.g., USSW2 CURNCY GIP) and see whether these things move intraday. If they don't, there's probably no reason for you to assess the relative value.. I mean what's the point of the model telling you 11y is cheap when you can't really trade on the signal...

Comment: Thanks that is another really good idea but I can't do that on a historic basis (or at least not very far back). It all seems a bit catch 22!!!

Comment: are you working with a trader? i used to just ask them which points they're interested in. Either way, you can assume that the points I mentioned (1,2,3,4,5,7,10,12,15,20,30) are well priced, fit your model using either 2s, 10s, 30s or 3m, 2s, 10s, and trade RV elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks again I agree that with live data you know what's real and what isn't but even with a trader on board it's hard to know what was real andw hat wasn't historically, will take your advice though seems a sensible starting point.

Comment: @Bazman Frankly, I don't think you need to be concerned about this. Different dealers have different models for curves, but as far as the par swap curve is concerned, everyone pretty much gets the same thing, even for the interpolated points (we're talking about difference of 0.x bp). Your model rich/cheap signals, on the other hand, should potentially be a lot more than 0.x bp. If the fit to the market is that good, then there's probably no money to be made after transaction cost...

Comment: I certainly hope so! At the short end what rates would you recommend using 3m future?

Comment: 3m libor works; some people use a rate interpolated using the first and second eurodollar futures contract (interpolated so that the rate is constant maturity).